# Importing existing spring project to Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, web-applications

I have the source of a spring project left by a colleague who has left. I am told to pick up the mess left by him. I am having difficulties to import it into Eclipise. I have experience in working on standalone apps with Eclipse, but not much for web apps. I know the project is built with Ant but I have no experience with Ant. I am kind of stuck here. I hope someone can help me out here.

So I have folder in this structure:

```
- src
    - main
        - ant
        - java
            - com (root package of the java code)
        - resources
        - webapp
    - test
        - java
            - com (root package)
```

There are also .classpath and .project files outside src folder which I don't know whether they are relevant to importing....

I have played around with the import wizard on Eclipse but couldn't quite work out what the right options are...

Thank you all in advance... Much much much appreciated.

Comment: `import -> general -> existing project into workspace`

Comment: Ah, I see. Previously I tried this and it didn't work because I didn't import the root folder of the project.